# QStorageInfo hangs GUI

Tags: c++, qt

In several Qt applications, compiled with mingGW 4.9.2-32 bit, I have this routine running properly to check if a USB drive with a specific label has been inserted:

```
void principal::datahora() {
    dhActual->setText(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
    static bool usb = false;
    connectat = false;
    foreach (const QStorageInfo &drive, QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes()) {
        if (drive.name() == unitatUSB)
        {
            connectat = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (connectat ^ usb) { // Have there been change?
        usb = connectat;
        if (connectat)
        {
            emit(estatUsb(true));
            // more stuff
        }
    }       
}
```

This routine runs every second according to a signal triggered by a `QTimer` and also shows the time on status bar (`dhactual` is a QLabel, `unitatUSB` is a QString, the USB label expected).
The signal `estatUSB` is connected to proper slots on open `QMainWindow`s or `QDialog`s, which take the appropiate actions on this.

When I have built this routine in a fully functioning application of one of my customers, suddenly the GUI hangs and the statusbar's clock updates both every 5 seconds, making the application useless. This has been the only change made.

The target machine runs Win 7 32 bit, and I have explored several possible causes, such as:

- The fake drive labeled 'Bluebirds', created by LG GH22NS50 firmware (DVD drive). When **physically** unplugged, all remains the same.
- The cards reader. I have disabled, with no change.
- In safe mode, the same thing happens.

No doubt that installing the Qt IDE and running the application in debug mode I could get some info on what happens, but this is for me the last resort (the target machine is in production and the time window for testing is narrow).

So, some of you can suggest the next steps to take, or point out some possible solution?

Thanks in advance,

## Edit for clarify:

I added one single function to application, that works fine in debug and release mode on other computers (and mine). In that perticular computer, the GUI hangs for 5 seconds every time the function iterates over the mounted volumes, regardless of whether an USB drive is connected or not.

Comment: Do they have any security software (antivirus, landesk, antimalware, etc.) that may be interfering with your application?

Comment: That was the first thing I deactivated.

Comment: It's not unheard of querying external drives being slow/hanging (especially with slow devices, defective media, antivirus software, ...), so I would avoid performing this kind of operation in the main thread in first place. Decouple it to a background thread, and keep the main thread always running to handle GUI events in acceptable time.

Comment: Also, last time I did something like that I didn't go with polling, but I just listened for `WM_DEVICECHANGE` messages; that would sidestep the problem completely, since you would have to perform the full enumeration only at program startup, although of course this solution would be Windows-only.

Comment: Please read my edit: "regardless of whether an USB drive is connected or not". The defective is the function, not the drive nor the media. And performs fine in several Windows applications I built in the function.

Comment: Code such as this which periodically monitors hardware and may block is probably better off on its own [`QThread`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html).  Any communication with other threads should be performed using [signals and slots with queued connections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).